# Remove gap during add layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am seeing gap into QVBoxLayout when I am placing layout it does not look good, any idea to fix issue

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QRegExp, QFile, QTextStream
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence, QTextCharFormat, QBrush,QColor, QTextDocument, QTextCursor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QMainWindow,
                               QPlainTextEdit, QGridLayout, QGroupBox,
                               QFormLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
                               QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QMessageBox,
                               QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QAction)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.width = 1100
        self.height = 700
        self.set_main_window()
        self.create_violation_text()
        
    def set_main_window(self):
        """
        Setting main window position
        """
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI %s" %(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(self.width, self.height))
        wid = QDesktopWidget() 
        screen_width = wid.screen().frameGeometry().width()
        screen_height = wid.screen().frameGeometry().height()
        self.setGeometry(screen_width/2-self.width/2,
                         screen_height/2-self.height/2, 
                         self.width, self.height)
    
    def create_violation_text(self):
        """
        creating main violation window which contain all violations
        """
        self.plain_textedit =  QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plain_textedit.setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit.NoWrap)
        self.plain_textedit.setStyleSheet(
        """QPlainTextEdit {font-size: 14pt;
                           font-family: Courier;}""")
    
    
class ReviewWindow(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, waiver_files, app):
        """creating Review mode"""
        super().__init__()
        self.waiver_files = waiver_files
        self.app = app
    
    def create_widget(self): 
        self.create_text_finder()
        self.create_violation_window()
        #order matter
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.text_finder)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.create_violation_box)
        #creating widgeth object as main window does not
        #add layout directly it add only widget
        window = QWidget()
        window.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(window)
    
    def create_text_finder(self):
        """
        create text finder which wil search string into document
        """
        self.text_finder = QGroupBox()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel()
        label.setText("Keyword:")
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setText("Enter your search here")
        push_button = QPushButton("Find")
        push_button.clicked.connect(self.find_string_match)
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(push_button)
        self.text_finder.setLayout(layout)
    
    def create_violation_window(self):
        """
        creating violation window which contain text editor,
        violation type and checkbox
        """
        self.create_violation_box = QGroupBox()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.plain_textedit, 1, 0, 12, 1)
        layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(0, 10)
        self.create_violation_box.setLayout(layout)
    
    def find_string_match(self):
        """
        Adding string match operation
        """
        #format for desire match
        format = QTextCharFormat()
        format.setBackground(QBrush(QColor("red")))
        pattern = QRegExp(self.line_edit.text())
        text_document = self.plain_textedit.document()
        #Reverting if any
        text_document.undo()
        if pattern.isEmpty():
            QMessageBox.warning("Search filed is empty")
        else:
            find_cursor = QTextCursor(text_document)
            cursor = QTextCursor(text_document)
            cursor.beginEditBlock()
            while (not find_cursor.isNull() and not find_cursor.atEnd()):
                found = False
                find_cursor = text_document.find(pattern, find_cursor,
                                                 QTextDocument.FindWholeWords)
                if (not find_cursor.isNull()):
                    found = True
                    find_cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.WordRight,
                                             QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
                    find_cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
            cursor.endEditBlock()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    waiver_file = \[os.path.join(cwd, fdata) for fdata in os.listdir(cwd)\]
    window = ReviewWindow(waiver_file, app)
    window.create_widget()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: your question is unclear, also provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc update thx for pointing out

Comment: try add `main_layout.setSpacing(0)`

Comment: that's it bit ignorance of mine

Comment: sorry it is not working

Comment: I have a curiosity: why do you use QGroupBox?

Comment: In real scenario,  I have texteditor, list widget, collection of checkbox which i have added into single groupbox